# How to delete items from a list in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have created an app.  One of the features in the app is making a list and saving to Isolated Storage.

To the point, my problem is with deleting items from the list.  To clarify, the user of the app can add items to list, and then save it.  I am also using a LongListMultiSelector, which I downloaded from the web.  What happens here is you can check items in a special boxes that pops-up (LongListMultiSelector feature). Up to this point, every feature works well. I want the user to be able to check the checkboxes, and press delete button, much like Windows Phone Hotmail, and rid of them.  This is the part where I am having trouble.

So I click the trash can button which should function as a delete button.  I have the following code for it.

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (LLMS.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            source.Remove((MainList)LLMS.SelectedItems[0]);
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
```

LLMS represents the LongListMultiSelector.
MainList is class and the list.

What happens is the app freezes up and stops working, though no pop-up comes up.

Comment: What do you currently have? Show some code so we can give you a solution based on what you already have. There are plenty of solutions to your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lines of code:

```
    void OnRemoveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IList source = MainList.ItemsSource as IList;

        while (MainList.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            source.Remove((**ObjectName**)MainList.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of a beginner, and I have a question what's IList?

Comment: IList represents a non-generic collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index. [More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I meant like, it always get a red underline, I guess because I never used it.

Comment: Add this line `using System.Collections;` to the class

Comment: IList is an Interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for several collection/list implementations.

To get rid of the "red underlining" (which probably indicates that it can't find the corresponding reference) you have to add a using directive to System.Collections. E.g.: `using System.Collections;`

Comment: thanks, I caught up with you idead now, just one question.  Exactly what do you mean by "**ObjectName**" and could you please explain  how to implement and object.

Comment: Using MainList.SelectedItems[0] you get an item of type object out of the collection, because thats the way its declared in the IList interface. To remove the items from your source collection, you first have to cast it to the type you have used, so it can be found and remove from that collection. That means (TYPE)yourItem makes sure that the item you want removed is of the desired type. We do not know which type you have used, but its name has to be used for the cast. e.g. if i have a class "Student" and i have a list of students (List<Student>()) i'd use myList.Remove((Student)selectedItem).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but do you know how to cast type and where you should cast one? @Tamay